# Using srcset for different device sizes AND resolutions

Tags: html, css, media-queries, srcset

i'm using this for the mobile version (media query) of my new page:

```
<!-- CSS is img{width=100%;height:auto} -->
<img src="360x1.jpg" srcset="360x1.jpg 1x, 360x2.jpg 2x, 360x3.jpg 3x">
```

Works fine so far on mobile phones and also with DPR ones...

So now the next step would be adding tablets (768px).

I thought it should be possible this way:

```
<img src="360x1.jpg" srcset="360x1.jpg 1x, 360x2.jpg 2x, 360x3.jpg 3x, 768x1.jpg 1x 768w, 768x2.jpg 2x 768w, 768x3.jpg 3x 768w">
```

So this would combine DPR and the device width. Would. :-)

I know the picture-tag but i'm not sure if this is the right solution. Also i know the sizes-attribute but...

Any idea how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From the [attribute descriptions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Attributes) for `<img>`:

> It is incorrect to mix width descriptors and pixel density descriptors
>   in the same `srcset` attribute.

Also, regarding using the `sizes` attribute with pixel density descriptors:

> If the `srcset` attribute is absent, or contains no values with a width
>   (`w`) descriptor, then the `sizes` attribute has no effect.

Instead of `<img>`, you could use `<picture>` with a `source` and corresponding `media` attribute for each device size including pixel density descriptors in the `srcset` attribute.

```html
<picture> 
   <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50 1x,
                   https://via.placeholder.com/100x100 2x"
           media="(max-width: 767px)">
   <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200 1x,
                   https://via.placeholder.com/400x400 2x">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="picture"> 
</picture>
```